# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges absolutely and $\sum _{n=1}^\infty a_{kn}=0 ,\forall k \ge 1 $ ; then $a_n=0 , \forall n \in \mathbb N $?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

Suppose that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ of real terms converges absolutely and $\sum _{n=1}^\infty a_{kn}=0  ,\forall k \in \mathbb N $ , then how to prove that $a_n=0 , \forall n \in \mathbb N $ ?

Comment: Hint: For every $n$ let $A(n)=\sum\limits_{k\geqslant1}a_{kn}$, then $$a_n=\sum_Q(-1)^{|Q|}A\left(n\prod\limits_{p\in Q}p\right)$$ where the sum is on every finite subset $Q$ of the set of prime numbers.

Comment: @Did: Could you please elaborate ?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30774/prove-that-a-n-0-for-all-n-if-sum-a-kn-0-for-all-k-geq-1

Comment: @SaunDev Sure -- but only if you explain what your problem with this formula is... otherwise what is the point?

Comment: @Did: I don't get the derivation itself and what are the consequences ?