# Infinite matrix is injective if all its upper left minors are invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

This is a natural generalization of a [recent MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1321398/on-absolutely-convergent-series-sum-n-1-inftya-n-such-that-sum-n-1).

Let $X=(x_k)_{k\geq 1}$ be a sequence of real numbers, and
$A=(a_{ij})_{i\geq 1,j\geq 1}$ be a real infinite matrix indexed
by ${\mathbb N}_{>0}$. Suppose that "$AX=0$" ; I mean by that that
for every $i\geq 1$, the series $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_{ij}x_j$ is convergent
with sum equal to zero.

Suppose also that for every $n\geq 1$, the upper left minor
$A_n=(a_{ij})_{1\leq i \leq n,1\leq j \leq n }$ is invertible.
Does it necessarily follow that all the $x_k$ are zero ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  An example is given by the following matrix:
$$ A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
                   0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & \cdots \\
                   0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & \cdots \\
                   \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \end{pmatrix} $$
with $X$ being the vector whose coordinates are all $1$.  Then $AX=0$, and all upper-left square submatrices $A_n$ have determinant $1$.