# On the convergence of a series involving Mobius functions (in the proof of a nice result)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analytic-number-theory

In [this nice answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/30775) to the question "Prove that $a_{n}=0$ for all $n$, if $\sum a_{kn}=0$ for all $k\geq 1$" it is required to show that following sum converges to $a_1$:
$$
\sum_{m=1}^\infty \left( \mu(m)\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{mn}\right),
$$
where $mn=m\times n$. This is not true in general when $\sum_n a_{mn}$ is not identically zero, but we are focusing on the case $\sum_n a_{mn}=0.$

Of course, the following cutoff version is always true:
$$
a_1= \sum_{mn\leq N} \mu(m)a_{mn}.
$$
However, it is really difficult to show that
$$
\sum_{mn\leq N} a_{mn} \to \sum_{m=1}^\infty \left( \mu(m)\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{mn}\right)
$$
as $N \to\infty$. I find myself always in need of some bounds on $\sum a_n$ related to the number of devisors of $n$, which is not provided by the fact that $\sum a_n$ is abosolutely convergent.

Absolute convergence of the double series is of course not always achievable.

And the entire thing is a **delicate unstable equilibrium**, because if we just require $|\sum \mu(m) a_{mn}| < \epsilon$ for all $n$, then it appears that we in general **cannot** conclude that $a_1<C\epsilon$ for some fixed constant $C$: there are counterexamples. We want $|\sum \mu(m) a_{mn}|$ to decrease fast with $m$, but unfortunately, we can make it decrease arbitrarily slow, by choosing $a_n$ to be a sequence with many zeros. To put it shortly, small perturbation in the sense of something like $l^\infty$ norm is unstable, and we are not free to choose other stronger norms.

So, **how to complete the proof of convergence?**

**It would be nice if further results of stability can be discussed as well.**

Comment: You left out the Mobius function.

Comment: @martycohen Thank you for pointing that out. It is now fixed.